# Executing ajax component http://path/to/my/component.cfc?method=something is not executing the method

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I have a CFC with a remote function and am trying to populate it into my cfm page's cfselect element. But I am not getting anything in the select.

I tried executing the cfc directly, but the method that I call does not execute.

Here is the code for the CFC:

```
    <cfcomponent output="false">
        <cffunction name="getYear" access="remote" returnType="query">

            <cfset yearlist = QueryNew("yr","integer")>
            <cfset temp = QueryAddRow(yearlist,3)>
            <cfset counter = 1>
            <cfloop from="#evaluate(year(Now())-1)#" to="#evaluate(year(Now())+1)#" index="y">
                <cfset temp = QuerySetCell(yearlist,"yr",y,counter)>
                <cfset counter = counter + 1>
            </cfloop>

            <cfreturn yearlist>
        </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Here is the code for the CFM

```
    <body>

    <cfform>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Select Year:</td>
            <td><cfselect name="yearval"
                        bind="cfc:cfc.ajaxcomp.getYear()"
                        value="yr"  
                        display="yr"
                        bindonload="true" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    </cfform>

</body>
```

Could you please tell me what am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So the following code works for me.  I changed a few things, so hard to know what did it but:

1. Var-scoped the variables
2. Removed some complexity
3. Changed the query column from integer to varchar

-

```
<cfcomponent output="false">
    <cffunction name="getYear" access="remote" returnType="query">

        <cfset var y = 0 />
        <cfset var yearList = QueryNew("yr","varchar")>

        <cfloop from="#year(Now())-1#" to="#year(Now())+1#" index="y">
            <cfset queryAddRow(yearList) />
            <cfset QuerySetCell(yearList,"yr",y)>
        </cfloop>

        <cfreturn yearlist>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```